# 2 rows differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get 2 consecutive rows from an SQL table.
One of the columns storing UNIX datestamp and between 2 rows the difference only this value.

For example:

```
       id_int    dt_int
1. row 8211721   509794233
2. row 8211722   509794233
```

I need only those rows where dt_int the same (edited)

Comment: Can you show a larger set of sample data along with the expected output?  Showing us two rows (and one column) of data somehow doesn't do it for me \:~(

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: 2008R2

Amount previousbalance currentbalance  depositamount dt_int
9691 116191                 106500             9691                8211721
70000 116191                 46191          70000              8211722

Comment: My problem is if 2 rows were inserted in same second the previousbalance wasn't updated and both rows used the same amount. I'd like to search which inserts came in the same second.

Comment: [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) is what you are looking for if using SQL Server 2012+

Comment: What defines the order of the rows and how/do we need to denote partitions/segments of rows to compare?  for example if this is an order table perhaps we should only be comparing records for the same customer?

Comment: 2008 R2 SQL server

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It's not clear what you want.  Before asking question, please learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Do you want both lines to be shown?

A solution could be this:

```
with foo as
(
select
*
from (values (8211721),(8211722),(8211728),(8211740),(8211741)) a(id_int)
)
select
id_int
from
(
select
    id_int
    ,id_int-isnull(lag(id_int,1) over (order by id_int) ,id_int-6) prev
    ,isnull(lead(id_int,1) over (order by id_int) ,id_int+6)-id_int nxt

from foo
) a
where prev<=5 or nxt<=5
```

We use lead and lag, to find the differences between rows, and keep the rows where there is less than or equal to 5 for the row before or after.

If you use 2008r2, then lag and lead are not available. You could use rownumber in stead:

```
with foo as
(
select
*
from (values (8211721),(8211722),(8211728),(8211740),(8211741)) a(id_int)
)
, rownums as
(
select
    id_int
    ,row_number() over (order by id_int) rn

from foo
) 
select 
    id_int
from
(
select
cur.id_int
,cur.id_int-prev.id_int prev
,nxt.id_int-cur.id_int nxt
from rownums cur
left join rownums prev
on cur.rn-1=prev.rn
left join rownums nxt
on cur.rn+1=nxt.rn
) a
where isnull(prev,6)<=5 or isnull(nxt,6)<=5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. This version works on SQL Server 2000 and above. Today I don not a more recent SQL Server to write on.

```
declare @t table (id_int int, dt_int int) 

INSERT @T SELECT 8211721 , 509794233
INSERT @T SELECT 8211722 , 509794233
INSERT @T SELECT 8211723 , 509794235
INSERT @T SELECT 8211724 , 509794236
INSERT @T SELECT 8211729 , 509794237
INSERT @T SELECT 8211731 , 509794238

;with cte_t as 
(SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_int) id
    ,id_int
    ,dt_int 

    FROM @t),
cte_diff as 
( SELECT 
     id_int
     ,dt_int
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 dt_int FROM cte_t b WHERE a.id < b.id) dt_int1   
    ,dt_int - (SELECT TOP 1 dt_int FROM cte_t b WHERE a.id < b.id) Difference
FROM cte_t a
) 
SELECT DISTINCT id_int , dt_int  FROM @t a 
WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte_diff b where b.Difference =0 and a.dt_int = b.dt_int)
```

Comment: works on `SQL 2000 *and* above` OR `above SQL 2000` ?

Comment: Tks :( @Squirrel.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong... I have to examine where dtint are the same not bigger or smaller. ALMOST GOOD  Please rewrite it. Thanks

Comment: Just change the **where** condition to **Difference = 0** in the both Exists at the end

Comment: ;with cte_t as 
(SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtint) id
    ,dtint FROM table),
cte_diff as 
( SELECT 
     dtint
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 dtint FROM table b WHERE a.dtint > b.dtint) dtint1
    ,dtint - (SELECT TOP 1 dtint FROM table b WHERE a.dtint > b.dtint) Diference
FROM cte_t a
)

SELECT dtint FROM table a 
WHERE 
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte_diff b where b.Diference =0 and a.dtint = b.dtint) 
    OR  EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte_diff c where c.Diference =0 and a.dtint = c.dtint1)

Comment: SELECT id_int FROM @t a 
    WHERE 
        EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM cte_diff b where b.Difference = 0 and a.id_int = b.id_int) 


with these no result.

Comment: 17 million rows :)

Comment: This table is a big table; this code will spend a lot of time. Do you need to analyze this quantity of data every day?
Try to works with subsets this data. What is the database version?

Comment: It will be once run. Compatibility level 100.

Comment: SQL Server 2008. I think you need to wait it finished.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- `lead()` analytical function available.
- ID_INT is what we need to sort by to determine table order...
- you may need to partition by some value `lead(ID_int) over(partition by SomeKeysuchasOrderNumber order by ID_int asc)`  so that orders and dates don't get mixed together.

.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT A.*
     , lead(ID_int) over ([missing partition info] ORDER BY id_Int asc) - id_int as ID_INT_DIFF
FROM Table A)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE ID_INT_DIFF < 5;
```